# Having Trouble Replicating WordPress IE Cross-Browser Issue

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, cross-browser, wordpress-theming

I've been having an issue with a client's site that I haven't been able to replicate. A few users have reported an issue with the website (http://beyondbbd.com) where the pages don't display a majority of the styling and render as below:

[image: A Screenshot of the issue]

In trying to troubleshoot, I am having difficulty replicating the issue on my browser checking system (Browserstack), or finding an underlying cause.

Users reporting the issue are using Windows 7 and Internet explorer (though I don't know their version of IE at this time), and are encountering the issue on these pages, among others:
http://beyondbbd.com/motivational-speakers-for-business/

http://beyondbbd.com/leadership-workshops/

http://beyondbbd.com/internal-coach-training-program/

I haven't been able to replicate on any version of Windows or IE using Browserstack, but this issue has been reported by more than one user so I don't think it's an isolated case.

Anyone have any ideas as to what the cause could be, or how I could replicate the bug?

Thanks in advance!

-Nick

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate, but you have two opening 'head' tags as well as lots of other validation errors (stray closing tags). It is possible that this is chocking some instances of IE.